# Funny symbols showing in a website

Tags: php, apache, centos

Simple question I'm hoping, on Server A everything shows okay, but on Server B it shows as follows

> Hello, how are you - Allo, comment vas-tu?  How much does it cost? -
>   Combien �a coute? or Quel est le prix de...?

Before my client kills me - How can I fix that? :)

Comment: We need more information to debug this. What web server is Server A. What web server is Server B? What code is responsibly for generating served content?

Comment: It is a decoding problem. Check if the second server has the same configuration as the first one. Also check if the files which have strange symbols are the same. Sometimes FTP managers do wrong things with files and change the code page for them.

Comment: Did you upload the db by copying and pasting the sql by any chance?

Comment: Does the webpage have a `DOCTYPE` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` (if the file is UTF-8 that is).

Comment: Server A was a 'hosted web server' no access to the internals or anything. Server A was bad, running PHP4 and other nasties!

Comment: Server B is my server, and I can get hold of any info about it if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your file is encoded in some encoding (say Latin-1) and your web server is configured to announce a different encoding in the HTTP header (say UTF-8), so the browser is misinterpreting the page's encoding. Make sure those two match, i.e. either change your server to send the correct HTTP header or encode your files in the matching encoding. Since you have given no detail of either I can't tell you how to do that in detail.

Comment: My research into this issue has also taken me down this road - I have been asking the client for more feedback in this area. I will cobble together some code to test this - Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I had to change the default charset on the web server, after that it was all good :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [these](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) codes instead. I this case I think you need the latin small letter c with cedilla written as

```
&ccedil;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using html codes you fint them here : http://www.usewisdom.com/computer/internet/html/chars.html

Or you could do it with a function like this

$text = "This a text with weird characters @#$%^&*";

echo htmlentities($text);

or if the site is in UTF-8 charset

echo utf_decode($text);

Comment: That's not a substitute for properly handling (i.e. *specifying*) encodings.